# How to change the appearance of the AMS Article title

Tags: titles, amsart

I am writing a document with `\documentclass{amsart}`. How do you change the appearance of the title in a document like this? It is set to all caps, bold, and a certain size. I can change it to italics with `\textit{}`, but I can't do anything else. I want to change the title to Large roman text. It seems like `\renewcommand{\title}` would work, but I don't know how to use this command. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine `\@settitle` and introduce your font modifications there; a little example suppressing the bold-faced font and using `\LARGE`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\def\@settitle{\begin{center}%
  \baselineskip14\p@\relax
    %\bfseries
    \normalfont\LARGE%<- NEW
\uppercasenonmath\@title
  \@title
  \end{center}%
}
\makeatother
\title{This is an interesting title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I should have mentioned that I wanted it to be with no capitalization. This was easy to fix, though; I just deleted `\uppercasenonmath\@title`. Thanks!

Comment: @fctaylor25 of course, you can do any adjustments that you require. You're welcome!